# Display a number decimal format instead as an exponential in cout

Tags: c++, cout

I calculated a total of floats and I got a number like `509990e-405`. I'm assuming this is the short version; how can I `cout` this as a full number?

```
   cout << NASATotal << endl;
```

is what I have now.

Comment: You want see 400 zeros in your output?

Comment: Well i did an exaggeration but yes i just want to know how to have the total output.

Comment: Although I do not know the computation you have done or the data you have done it on, I suspect this number to be wrong or at least completely useless result. As pure cuteness wrote, it's a number with 400 zeros after the decimal point.

Comment: I added 1000 floats with 1.36236 whatever haha

Comment: @Martin actually it's 509990 * 10^(-405)

Comment: You do realize that this is essentially zero, right?

Comment: mystycs, I know you're a beginner, but seriously, you should be able to see that this result is spurious. There's no way you can add a handful of floats and get this as a result. Please don't post questions like this without acknowledging that you're just goofing around.

Comment: Ooops: This is the same as: 509990 * (1/10^405)

Comment: @sonicboom You could also use a simple `printf("%.405f", NASATotal);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the output to be not in scientific notation, and to have the sufficient precision to show your small number.

```
#include <iomanip>

// ...

long double d = 509990e-405L;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(410) << d << std::endl;
```

Output:

> 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050999000000

If you really *want* this is another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own BigNumber class that stores the results as strings. You would have to implement all of your numeric operations and I'm guessing performance will be an issue. But it can be done, no problem -- assuming that is what you want.

Comment: Soo i should make it into a string?

Comment: no, i was thinking instead of using int or float, use your BigNumber class that you'll implement :-) (something like this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/27746-big-number-class/)