# Getting a weird result

Tags: c++

```
float k,n,s,p;
float a,d;
cin>>k>>n>>s>>p;
a=n/s;
a=ceil(a);
d=k*a;
d=d/p;
cout<<ceil(d);
```

Am getting an output = **1e+008** when the inputs are **10000, 10000, 1, 1**.
The actual result should be **100000000**.
I tried using double instead of float but no success.
Kindly throw some light

Comment: Those are the same value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display a number decimal format instead as an exponential in cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998367/display-a-number-decimal-format-instead-as-an-exponential-in-cout)

Comment: yes that does. I was unsure about what to search. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)

```
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(8)<<d<<endl;
```

Comment: it solved my problem thank you

Comment: You should accept the answer so next time if any person has same problem he can find it easily.